# Calculus II: Find the Volume (Shell-Method)

Tags: integration, proof-verification, volume

Find the volume of the shape created when rotating the region(s) bounded by $y=\sqrt{x+1}, y=0, x=0, x=1$, about the x-axis.

I know this is a rudimentary question.  My issue is that I tried to test myself using the shell method instead of using the disk-method.  I have been taught that both methods work, yet what I assumed to be correct usage of the shell method in this instance garnered me an incorrect answer.  I am not asking to see the disk method or why it would have been easier, I am asking what went wrong with my usage of the shell method.

\begin{align*}                                
V &= \int_0^\sqrt{2}2\pi(y)({y^2}-1)dy \\
&=2\pi\int_0^\sqrt{2}({y^3}-y)dy \\
&=2\pi\left[\frac{y^4}4-\frac{y^2}2\right]{\sqrt{2} \choose 0} \\
&=2\pi\left(\frac44-\frac22\right) \\
&=2\pi(0) \\
&=0 
\end{align*}
... where of course  $x = {y^2}-1$ and $y=\sqrt{1+1}$
= $\sqrt{2}$

Thanks!

Comment: you need to integrate from $0$ to $\sqrt{0+1}=\sqrt{1}=1$.

Comment: The "height" of the cylindrical shell is different from $y=0$ to $y=1$ than it is from $y=1$ to $y=\sqrt{2}$. So we need to break up the integral into two parts. (One of the parts is a cylinder so does not require integration.)

Answer (score 1):

As Andre Nicolas pointed out, you need two integrals using the shell method;

and you also need a different expression for the height:

$\displaystyle V=\int_0^1 2\pi r(y)h(y)dy+\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi r(y)h(y)dy=\int_0^1 2\pi y(1)dy+\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} 2\pi y(1-(y^2-1))dy$